# Heading in alt-tag (alt='<h1>Test</h1>')

Tags: html, css, image, alt, html-heading

I have an image with a link. If there, for some reason, is no image I would like the "image" to display a heading. I am coding this in PHP, and this is my line of code:

```
<a href='LINK.php?img=$id'><img src='$filename' alt='<h1>$username</h1>' width='500'></a>
```

It is not working, and the out put is "`<h1>jerry></h1>`" in plain text, no heading, if the $username is jerry.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You can't output HTML in attributes like alt and title.

Comment: Are you refering to `$filename` to be None, or non existent images ?

Comment: You need to look for some plugin's like a tooltip, alt can have only `text` content not html content...

Comment: Is there a particular reason the image cannot be within h1 tags?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the file exists before outputting the html.

```
if(file_exists($filename)){ 

    echo "<img src='".$filename."' alt='".$username."' width='500' />";

}else{

    echo "<h1>".$username."</h1>";

}
```

If you'd rather not tie up PHP checking for these files you can also use the onerror="" event to use javascript to modify this information for you.

In the head include this;

```
<script>

    function switchImage(obj,un){ 

        obj.remove();

        document.getElementById("userImage").innerHTML = "<h1>" + un + "</h1>";

    }

</script>
```

For the link/header do this:

```
echo "<a href='LINK.php?img=".$id."' id='userImage'><img onerror='switchImage(this,\"".$username."\");' src='".$filename."' alt='".$username."' width='500'></a>";
```

Comment: Might not work, file_exists requires an absolute path if im correct. Just add `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`  in from of it

Comment: Agreed but that really depends on what the variable actually stores. In the case of the question it's somewhat ambiguous. It could be the entire URL or just the filename inside the folder with the PHP file.

Comment: misses the case when a user disables images.

Comment: That's what an alt tag is for and user's disabling images expect that kind of behavior.

Comment: $filename is an absolute link to the picture (www.blabla.com/img/test1.png). 

Your script doesn't work for me! Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah because then absolute path can't be used with file_exists(). You have a couple options though. If these files are on the same domain you can modify the string using str_replace() to replace, the www.blabla.com part with the appropriate "../" to navigate to the file. If this isn't a good option, (files are on a different server, can't reliably discern location), just use fopen($url) or a curl() alternative to figure out if the file exists. You have many options!

Comment: The javascript option I just provided should be very easy to implement and possibly be a lot nicer on your coding demands.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible, that is not what the alt is for. Alt is short for 'alternative text'. It is the text displayed when the image has not loaded (yet).

Also, if you want that to work, you should have used the `title` attribute. Same rules, but it is the text been shown when you hover over it.

I think the solution you need is a tooltip script. There are plenty of those to find, many different styles, so it isn't that hard to find one you like.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Check if the file exists in the PHP code, and conditionalize what markup is rendered. This assumes the image located on the same server the PHP code is running in.

```
$relUrlPath = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $filename);
if(file_exists( realpath("." . $relUrlPath) ))
   echo "<h1><img src='$filename' alt='$username' width='500'><h1>";
else
   echo "<h1>Jerry</h1>";
```

Comment: $filename is an absolute link to the picture (www.blabla.com/img/test1.png). 

Your script doesn't work for me! Do you know why?

Comment: Is the image located on the same server as where the PHP code is running? If not, this code will not work for you. `realpath` will convert a local webpath to a physical file path which you can then use `file_exists` to see if the file is there.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
<h1><a href='LINK.php?img=$id'><img src='$filename' alt='$username' width='500'></a></h1>
```

Same effect, better SEO, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

That's the nature of the alt tag; it's plain-text.

You can apply text styles to that image, and they'll apply to any text displayed in its place.  e.g.:

```
<a href='LINK.php?img=$id'><img src='$filename' class='headerimg' alt='$username' width='500'></a>
```

and then have your CSS style that in `h1` fashion:

```
.headerimg {
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 120%;
   /* etc. */
}
```

Comment: I didnt +1 you (I almost did :P) because even though this works, its not the way it should be used. The alt only exists for alternat5ive text, it should not be used and styled as text

Comment: Perfekt solution! Thanks!

Comment: While adding the css and class will affect the alt text albeit strange and perhaps extraneous you should remove the <h1> tags from the alt attribute. This is not valid markup and should be down voted otherwise.

Comment: Oops, meant to do that. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

If your use of `h1` is correct in the first place, it should be an `h1` even if the image is loaded correctly:

```
<h1><a href=""><img src="" alt="" /></a></h1>
```

If your use of `h1` is not correct, e.g. you only use it because of its default CSS presentation, you shouldn’t use `h1` at all.

Don’t misuse `alt`. If you need a custom attribute for your stuff™, use the [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Some images might need a more complex alternative text. In that case, you may use the [`longdesc` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-longdesc/). Or go with the [`object` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element):

```
<object data="img.png" type="image/png">
  <!-- the alternative content goes here -->
  <h1>…</h1>
  <p>…</p>
</object>
```